# Facebook will not ask the required permission on log in

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to ask for email permission, but it won't show up when the FB pop up opens.

The button is custom button, so I don't ask permissions on the html (as some here said solves the problem) but on this function :

```
function FBlogin()
  {

             FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected')
                {
                  console.log("connected");
                  testAPI();
                }
                else
                 {
                  console.log("not connected");
                 }
              },{scope: 'public_profile,email'});

  }
```

Which will later return `null`, and will also not even ask me for this permission.

Also - how can I "reset" `Chrome` from identifying that the user already logged in (not showing the FB popup again)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried your permissions on a Facebook integration on a personal app, it asked me that the app will access my "names, profile picture and email", then I accepted.

After that, I disconnected/reconnected and it didn't ask me to accept permissions again.

If you wish to be asked again, go to your `FB profile > Carret dropdown > Parameters > Apps & websites`, and delete your app.

To check if a user is already connected, you can check in `FB.getLoginStatus()` if status is `connected` and abort your connection process.

Hence, you can get the email with

`FB.api('/me?fields=email', res => console.log(res.email))`

Comment: Do you need access token to get the email? because email and ages will return undefined for me..

Comment: Check you're well connected with `FB.getLoginStatus()` and with the good permissions. There is no reason it not work if you are and your profile got a email address.

Comment: or: `FB.api('/me', {fields: 'email'}, res => console.log(res.email));` (api endpoint + parameters)